# Android - proper way to create paid version of currently free app

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase

What is the optimal way how to add paid features to my current app, which is already published in store for free ?

I have understanding about adding flavors to app (like free and pro flavor) and based on this prepare different classes and resources.

Anyway looking into Google Play console - quoting "Once your app has been offered for Free, the app can't be changed to Paid. If you want to charge for the app, you need to create a new app with a new package name and set a price."

Adding 2nd app with diferent package name and PRO features will result my users loosing their original data and settings from free app. Hmmm...

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 types of app you can upload Paid( Charge user for download) and Free (Available free to download) This is when you first upload your app in google console.
You can still add paid features to your free app but you can't charge users for downloading app (Both have diff. meaning)

> "Once your app has been offered for Free, the app can't be changed to Paid. If you want to charge for the app, you need to create a new app with a new package name and set a price."

For paid features with your free downloadable app you need to add billing .
Here [Google Play Billing Overview](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview)